# efficient image compression for pdf embedding with linux

Tags: linux, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, djvu

I would like to compress scanned text (monochrome or few colours) and store it in pdf (maybe djvu) files. I remember that I got very good results with Windows/Acrobat and "ZRLE" compressed monochrome tiff embedded into pdf. The algorithm was loossless as far as I remember. Now I search a way to obtain good results on linux. It should be storage saving and avoid loss (I do not mind loosing colours, but I do not want e.g. jpeg compression which would create noisy results for text scans). I need it for batch conversion, so I was thinking of the ImageMagick convert command. But which output format should I use so I get good results and to be able to embed it into pdf files (for example using pdflatex)? Or is it generally better to use djvu files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jbig2enc** encoder for images using jbig2 compression, 
was originally written for GoogleBooks by **Adam Langley**

https://github.com/agl/jbig2enc

I forked to include latest improvements By Rubypdf and others

https://github.com/DingoDog/jbig2enc

I also built several binaries of **jbig2enc** for **puppy linux** (it can be working also on other distributions)

http://dokupuppylinux.info/programs:encoders

Answer (score 2):

DJVU is not a bad choice, but if you want to stay in PDF for better compatibility you may want to look into [lossless JBIG2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBIG2) compression.

Quote from Wikipedia:

> Overall, the algorithm used by JBIG2 to compress text is very similar
>   to the JB2 compression scheme used in the DjVu file format for coding
>   binary images.

Comment: I see, works with convert command. What about LZW compression? It seems to work with 8-bit colour images as well. Does it? http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/suppl/imagemagick/www/Magick.html says that there are license issues. But according to the same page the license ends in 2002. Is there still reason not to use it? How can I use it with convert? "convert -compress LZW fig.png fig.tif" does not lead to significant compression in my ImageMagick. Do I need to install additioanl software?